# Determining projection of Albanian military map?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I've received some very useful maps of Albania for my work (scale 1:25000) and I would like to georeference them in order to put them together to one Map for my destined regions.

Unfortunately I cannot find the projection of the maps, they don't seem to be written on the map (it is unfortunately in Albanian language).

What projection might it be?

I'm using QGIS.

[image]

[full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2neRN.jpg)

Comment: The coordinate system is printed on the left upper corner in Albanian. It says "The national coordinate system".
On the upper right side it says "SEKRETE" meaning classified map. Congratulations!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General projection of these maps is Pulkovo 1942/ Gauss-Kruger zone[zone number]. For this particular map it is Pulkovo 1942/ Gauss-Kruger zone 4

EPSG:28404; proj4 code:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.92,-141.27,-80.9,-0,0.35,0.82,-0.12 +units=m +no_defs
```

**UPD**: I fixed incorrect zone number 3 -> 4

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Where could you see this on this map?

Comment: Ok Now I don't have the slighest idea how to read to koordinates. If I type for example X: 42054662 and y: 2022(30??)4449 (koordinates in the down-left corner of the map) I stay somewhere near Africa. How do I have to interpret those numbers? Sorry I feel very dumb now :(

Comment: @Luka, I'm just familiar with these Soviet-school military maps. You need to add 000 to each coordinate when you georeference it: 4662 -> 4662000; 4458 -> 4458000

Comment: Hi there, it's me again. And I'm asking myself: The Projection you suggested is suggested to use for a  different area (http://georepository.com/crs_28404/Pulkovo-1942-Gauss-Kruger-zone-4.html) more around Poland... Are you sure this was right? Sorry to be so pushy

Comment: @Lukas, I'm sure. This CRS (don't mess CRS and projection) is suitable for any area within the certain longitudes (and Albania share same longitudes with Poland). You should find a handbook on geodesy if you want to be familiar with how this CRS staff works.